# is there some way we can react to the user zoom event?

Tags: javascript, html, css

When we go to apple's website: *sbsstatic*/maintenance.html?start=0&tstart=0">https://discussions.apple.com/***sbsstatic***/maintenance.html?start=0&tstart=0

and we do some zooming (Ctrl + and Ctlr -0), we can see the top bar has a sliding effect while we are zooming.

Does anyone know of any ideas how would/could that be implemented?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no onzoom event even in HTML5:

http://www.w3schools.com/html5/html5_ref_eventattributes.asp

"One way to detect zoom level changes relies on the fact that percentage values are not zoomed. A percentage value is relative to the viewport width, and thus unaffected by page zoom. If you insert two elements, one with a position in percentages, and one with the same position in pixels, they’ll move apart when the page is zoomed. Find the ratio between the positions of both elements and you’ve got the zoom level."

http://novemberborn.net/2007/12/javascriptpage-zoom-ff3-128

Comment: w3fools do not list any errors in eventattributes page. Besides that w3schools is source like any other. There is nothing especially wrong with it.

Comment: @Jacek so are you saying we run an infinite loop that does the check?

Comment: @Pacerier yes, using setTimeout

Comment: @Jacek why did you choose `setTimeout` over `setInterval` in this case?

Comment: @Pacerier - mistake, I was thinking about setInterval

Answer (score 0):

## Yes!

Yes, write a keyboard event handler or us a Library like this:
http://www.openjs.com/scripts/events/keyboard_shortcuts/

Answer (score 0):

This is using some CSS Animation tricks. There's a tutorial [here](http://www.the-art-of-web.com/css/css-animation/).

A sample of the type of style (from the above tutorial) that will give you the effect your looking for:

```
<div style="-webkit-transform: scale(2); -moz-transform: scale(2); -o-transform: scale(2);">...</div>
```

You can take a look at their "enhanced" style sheet that sorts this out [here](https://discussions.apple.com/themes/apple/styles/enhanced.css).

Comment: but what has this got to do with when i zoom in and out?

Comment: @Pacerier Your question asked how the apple thing worked...as I understand it this is exactly how it works so probably a bit harsh to downvote the answer. The CSS above creates a div that changes relative to your zoom level. Check out the tutorial I linked to...scroll down, look at the boxes and zoom in. Same effect in a very simple manner.

Comment: @Pacerier cool ok no worries, no other comments so no idea why someone did...thought I was answering the Q! :)

Are you happy with how this CSS trick works now? It's quite cool and Apple have done the best implementation I've seen...